# What is select[dbo].[SqlManagement](1) in MS Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I often run this script to see whats taking up time and slowing down my server

```
SELECT top 10  last_execution_time  ,execution_count  , total_worker_time  ,  total_elapsed_time , Text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) 
order by total_elapsed_time desc
```

Always the hardest worker, taking up the most cpu is "select[dbo].SqlManagement", but googling doesn't give any info what this is and how to get rid of it

I only found one relevant link https://developpaper.com/decryption-of-new-sql-server-file-free-persistence-malicious-programs/ which seems to state that this is a virus. Is that correct? and if yes, how can I remove it?

SQL Server Version:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4505219) - 13.0.4259.0 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 19:20:12   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials 6.3  (Build 9600: )

**Update**
I found the sproc in the master database. But it shows with a little lock icon. Trying to view it (even from sa account) gives the following error:

> Property TextHeader is not available for StoredProcedure
> '[dbo].[sp_sql_management]'. This property may not exist for this
> object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.
> The text is encrypted. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17289.0+((SSMS_Rel_17_4).181117-0805)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.PropertyCannotBeRetrievedExceptionText&EvtID=TextHeader&LinkId=20476

So i just went ahead and dropped it. I hope I didnt just kill my database :-)

Please advise

I appreciate

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see a function called `SqlManagement()` in your database's user-defined functions (like the article you linked mentions)? Maybe adding the results of your performance monitoring query to the post will add more context too.

Comment: Yes I do! (only now did i realize i should look in "master"). is it a virus? shall i drop it? it shows with a little lock near it, and i cant "alter" it.

Comment: It might be a virus. Possibly relevant https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/54204.sql-server-troubleshooting-how-to-remove-new-mrbminer-malware.aspx